# Manual DOM updates and React Component Rendering using forceUpdate()

Tags: reactjs, dom

I have a very simple application with a component that wraps two children. It also contains a button that forces a re-renders.

```
const Hello = () => <span id="hello">hello</span>;
const World = () => <span id="world">world</span>;

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="hello-world">
        <Hello />
        <World />
        <button onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()}>re-render</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Using the following code, I can rearrange the DOM, such that `Hello` comes after `World`

```
var hello = document.getElementById('hello-world').children[0]
var world = document.getElementById('hello-world').children[1]
hello.parentNode.insertBefore(world, hello)
```

When I force a re-render, I expect React to render to the DOM what it has represented in its virtual DOM (`Hello World`). Instead it continues to render `World Hello`. Why is this? In what cases will manual DOM updates like this cause problems?

Comment: What you want to do is use props or state to re-render the change. When you manipulate the DOM directly like that the virtual dom diffing may not see the changes.

Comment: @mhatch I know that you shouldn't do this in practice - but I'm wondering why DOM manipulations seem to persist even after a component re-renders.

Comment: I would expect that they persist because that part of the component is not updated. forceupdate forces a call of render, not a refresh of data properties. Now, if you refresh the page, I'm sure that it will revert.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem (dynamic component rendering), I would have used an array, and have the order changed by the forceUpdate().

```
helloWorld = [Hello, World];
```

and have it render with a map to give it a key :

```
render() {
 return (
   <div>{
     helloWorld.map(Item => (<Item key={ uniqueVar } />)
   )
  }</div>
 )
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an explanation for why the manual DOM updates persist even after component re-rendering. I'm not looking for alternatives to the above, which I would never do in practice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate):

> Calling forceUpdate() will cause render() to be called on the
>   component, skipping shouldComponentUpdate(). This will trigger the
>   normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the
>   shouldComponentUpdate() method of each child. React will still only
>   update the DOM if the markup changes.

This means that `render()` will be called, but if your data hasn't changed, those parts of the dom will not update - they are the same.